# Java, write in file by saving the old inputs and adding the new inputs in new lines

Tags: java

Whenever I compile my project, I get a input message. By clicking OK it saves my "password" in a txt file.
After repeating the above, the old "password" has changed with the new one I've type'd in.
How can I avoid that ?
I've tried `pw.println("\r\n"+x);`, `pw.println("\n"+x);` and such but I haven't managed to get it working as I want.

Here's my code:

```
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("number.txt")) {
        int x = readInt();
        pw.println(x);
        pw.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem with the output file");
    }
```

and my readInt method (in case you wanna know):

```
public static int readInt() {
    String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your password");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: what you are ACTUALLY looking for is a logging-framework like log4j : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm.
Oh and besides : logging passwords is highly problematic - that may get you into legal problems someday. NEVER log passwords.

Comment: It's just for a university project, have been asked to log player's password on a txt file so don't worry about it =) I'll check the stuff you've provided btw, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrintWriter will truncate an existing file to zero bytes (i.e. empty it).

You'll need to open the file in append mode like so:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("number.txt", true));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to open `PrintWriter` in append mode. To be more precise you need to wrap OutputStream or Writer which supports this mode. You can use

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("number.txt", true));
//                                                            ^^^^
```

or since [it will internally use `FileOutputStream`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/FileWriter.java#76) you can skip one level of encapsulation and use directly

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("number.txt", true))
```

but this will not change much.

---

BTW since you are using [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) you don't need to explicitly call `pw.close()`. It will be called automatically.

Comment: Compiler says "no suitable constructor found for PrintWriter..."

Comment: @NikosPappas That is strange. I am not sure since which Java version this constructor is available (I suspect that from where Writers ware added) but it is available even in Java 5 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream). Could you show hod you are using it (link to pastebin.com containing code example will be fine).

Comment: Weird but when I saw your answer, it was showing "PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("number.txt", true))
//                   to me...now I see new FileOutputStream added but is that correct or davids FileWriter instead ?

Comment: @NikosPappas I didn't change code in my answer. Anyway code in both answers (mine and Davids) will use `FileOutputStream` internally (mine will just skip one level of encapsulation).

Comment: you definitelly know too much about programming but just 'cause Davids answer was the first one which helped me (perhaps I was blind when I was reading yours.. but even with the ctrl+z that I did, I don't see the "new FileOutputStream" I've to choose his answer :/

Comment: @NikosPappas "*cause Davids answer was the first one*" you need to do your math again (mine answer has 36 minutes, Davids 34 minutes, which is older?). But I don't mind which answer you will mark as solution as long as it is correct one :)

Comment: "I don't see the `new FileOutputStream`" you need to import it first via `import java.io.FileOutputStream;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem if I get it right is that you are overwriting the file each time. Try reading the file contents, putting that into a string, appending the new password to the end of that and then writing the resulting string into the txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Pass true in the writer object's constructor, it'll append data at the end of file every time you invoke write method.